# Usei o if e else de forma errada?

Tags: c

Comei a programar a pouco tempo e estou tentando aprender C porem me deparei com um erro que não consigo resolver.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int A, B, C[7], D[7], E[7], S[1];
    S[0] = 998; //Salario minimo

    //Recolhe a informação de quantas pessoas trabalham na sua casa
    printf("Quantas pessoas trabalham na sua casa ? /n");
    scanf("%d", &A);

    //Reconhe a informação de quantas pessoas vivem na sua casa
    printf("Quantas pessoas vivem na sua casa ? /n");
    scanf("%d", &B);

    //Recolhe os dados inseridos do valor de salarios das pessoas que trabalham na sua casa
    if(A==1){
        printf("Digite o ultimo salario da pessoa que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);
    }

    if(A==2){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);
    }

    if(A==3){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);
    } 

    if(A==4){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quarta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[3]);
    }   

    if(A==5){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quarta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[3]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quinta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[4]);
    }    

    if(A==6){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quarta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[3]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quinta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[4]);

        printf("Digite o salario da sexta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[5]);
    }

    if(A==7){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa. /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quarta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[3]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quinta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[4]);

        printf("Digite o salario da sexta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[5]);

        printf("Digite o salario da setima pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[6]);
    }

    if(A==8){
        printf("Digite os ultimos salario das pessoas que trabalha na sua casa.  /n");

        printf("Digite o salario da primeira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[0]);

        printf("Digite o salario da segunda pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[1]);

        printf("Digite o salario da terceira pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[2]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quarta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[3]);

        printf("Digite o salario da quinta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[4]);

        printf("Digite o salario da sexta pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[5]);

        printf("Digite o salario da setima pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[6]);

        printf("Digite o salario da oitava pessoa. /n");
        scanf("%d", &C[7]);
    }

    //soma dos salarios dos membros empregados
    D[0] = C[0];

    D[1] = C[0] + C[1];

    D[2] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2];

    D[3] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2] + C[3];

    D[4] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2] + C[3] + C[4];

    D[5] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2] + C[3] + C[4] + C[5];

    D[6] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2] + C[3]+ C[4] + C[5] + C[6];

    D[7] = C[0] + C[1] + C[2] + C[3] + C[4] + C[5] + C[6] + C[7];

    //divisão dos salarios pelo numero de moradores
    E[0] = D[0] / B;

    E[1] = D[1] / B;

    E[2] = D[2] / B;

    E[3] = D[3] / B;

    E[4] = D[4] / B;

    E[5] = D[5] / B;

    E[6] = D[6] / B;

    E[7] = D[7] / B;

    //armazena o salario minimo vezes tres
    S[1] = S[0] * 3;

    //printa o resultando dizendo se a renda é maior ou menor de 3 salarios minimos
    if(E[0] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[1] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[2] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[3] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[4] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[5] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[6] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    if(E[7] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    return 0;
}
```

O seguinte código está imprimindo no console todas as opções contidas no código quando era para imprimir só uma das opções.

[image: Imagem do erro]

Oque errei? Como posso resolver?

Comment: Izaac, para quebrar as linhas utiliza a barra inversa "\n".

Comment: Outra coisa, nos códigos mais abaixo, sempre tem um "if / else", ou seja, sempre vai cair em uma ou outra. Você poderia verificar a lógica desses "if / else" para ver qual deles irá utilizar.

Comment: não cole imagem, como você fez ao mostrar o resultado, faça copiar e colar do *texto*...sem contar que sua imagem está minúscula

Comment: Porq não experimenta usar um `switch...case` na entrada de dados, além do bom e velho `for`para iterar sobre esses arrays??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no código, você não informa qual das opções você gostaria que fosse impressa, o sistema imprime todas elas.

Esse problema específico poderia ser resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
if(A == 1){

      if(E[0] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    }
    if(A == 2) {

      if(E[1] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    }
    if(A == 3){
      if(E[2] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");

    }

    if(A == 4) {
      if(E[3] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    }

    if(A == 5){
      if(E[4] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    }

    if(A == 6){
      if(E[5] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    }

    if(A == 7){
      if(E[6] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    }
   if(A == 8){
      if(E[7] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
   }
```

Eu imagino que você tenha usado esse tipo de solução, porque ainda não aprendeu ou não pode usar `for`, mas é importante destacar que um loop seria mais apropriado nesse seu programa. Algo do tipo:

```
int total_rendimentos = 0;
   int i;
   //soma dos salarios empregados
   for (i = 0; i < A; i++){
      total_rendimentos += C[i];
   }
   //divisao do salario pelo número de moradores
   int renda_media = total_rendimentos / B;

   //armazena o salario minimo vezes tres
    S[1] = S[0] * 3;

   //printa o resultando dizendo se a renda é maior ou menor de 3 salarios minimos
   if(renda_media > S[1]){
       printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
   }
    else{
        printf("Sua renda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
   }
```

E, por fim, seu programa tem alguns erros que precisam ser corrigidos. Um deles, como observado nos comentários, é que para quebrar linhas se utiliza a barra inversa e não a barra normal, e.g. `\n`. E outro erro, esse particularmente grave, é que você está escrevendo fora dos limites dos arrays que você declarou. Na primeira linha, o correto seria:

```
int A, B, C[8], D[8], E[8], S[2];
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, estou aprendendo aos poucos ainda não sei como utilizar certas coisas mas agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta fazendo a verificação independente da quantidade de moradores, precisa fazer essa verificação antes de fazer a verificação da renda:

```
if (A == 1){
    if(E[0] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
} else if (A == 2){
    if(E[1] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
} else if (A == 3){
    if(E[2] > S[1])
        printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
    else
        printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
}
```

---

Essa parte do código extensa, pode ser reduzida para uma única condição:

```
if(E[A - 1] > S[1])
    printf("Sua renda é superior a 3 salarios minimos!");
else
    printf("Sua reda é inferior a 3 salarios minimos!");
```

Explicando a solução, `A` contém o número de moradores, subtraindo 1 teremos a posição do array onde se encontra a divisão por moradores.